# After pushing changes from one client to a remote repository, how can I get them into the workspace of another?

Tags: git

Every time I push changes from my git repo to my staging server, I have to use the following command to complete overwrite the changes.

```
git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/master
```

Why can't I just do `git fetch`?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to overwrite the changes?

Comment: As in I make changes locally, push them to the staging server, but the changes never reflect. until I use the git reset.

Comment: I'm doubtful that they're not reflecting on the server; it could be that the metric being used to see the changes on the server is inaccurate.  Would you mind sharing what commands you invoke to push to your staging server, and how you check to see that they've been successfully propagated?

Comment: @Makoto I push with `git push origin master` and I don't use a command to see if it was successful. I should though. However, @eckes's solution fixed it.

Comment: If `push` does not print an error it is pretty sure it succeeded (unless your screen goes black in that moment :) However it does not hurt to run "git fetch" it will spot such differences.

Comment: The `push` works perfectly fine, my remote git repo reflects those changes aswell so no problem there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pull changes you need to use `git pull` not `git fetch`. fetch does only download the changes into the repository (and updates the remote branches). It does not update the workspace.

`git pull` is a shortcut for `git fetch && git merge <branch>`. See for example the [GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/fetching-a-remote/).

I typically use an `alias fe = fetch --all -v -progress -p` which I run often just to see what changes and differences happen. This can be done without thinking as it does not touch your workspace, require merging or similar (that is why `git fetch` is a useful command even if it has no obvious effect to the workspace). It does for example help with `git status` as it can tell you, that you are behind the remote branch (and need to run `git pull --ff-only` or similar).

Comment: Welcome, @RichardA feel free to accept it as an answer. I added some more hints. BTW: I think the question is a bit confusing as you talk about a "staging server" which is not a git concept. So I think you mean "after pushing changes from one client to a remote repository, how can I get them into the workspace of another"?

Comment: I will, but SO made me wait. (you apparently can't accept any answer until 10 minutes after the first one (needs confirmation)?) And yes, that might've been a better title.

Comment: I changed the title so it's more appropriate to git.